# Can't use imported class as a return type in TypeScript

Tags: import, module, typescript, export, ecmascript-6

[image]

I can't use imported `Command` class as a return type even if it is possible to create `Command` instance like (`let parser = new Command();`)

My `tsc` version is,

```
$ src git:(master) ✗ tsc --version
Version 1.8.0-dev.20151222
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `commander.IExportedCommand.Command` [is not](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1ee457510633b5bdde96f2519ecde2107bc23b6b/commander/commander.d.ts#L403) a type but a variable. You can either use `typeof Command` or use the actual name of that type `commander.ICommand`.

```
function create(args: string[]): typeof Command;
// or
function create(args: string[]): commander.ICommand;
```