# Use commander in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, definitelytyped, node-commander

I try to use commander in typescript and I could like to give a proper type to my cli. So I start with this code:

```
import * as program from "commander";

const cli = program
  .version("1.0.0")
  .usage("[options]")
  .option("-d, --debug", "activate more debug messages. Can be set by env var DEBUG.", false)
  .parse(process.argv);

console.log(cli.debug)
```

But I get this error:

```
example.ts(9,17): error TS2339: Property 'debug' does not exist on type 'Command'.
```

So I tried to add an interface, as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199787/how-can-i-use-commander-npm-with-typescript):

```
import * as program from "commander";

interface InterfaceCLI extends commander.Command {
  debug?: boolean;
}

const cli: InterfaceCLI = program
  .version("1.0.0")
  .usage("[options]")
  .option("-d, --debug", "activate more debug messages. Can be set by env var DEBUG.", false)
  .parse(process.argv);

console.log(cli.debug)
```

and I get this error:

```
example.ts(3,32): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'commander'.
```

From what I understand, `cli` is actually a class of type `commander.Command` So I tried to add a class:

```
import * as program from "commander";

class Cli extends program.Command {
    public debug: boolean;
}

const cli: Cli = program
  .version("1.0.0")
  .usage("[options]")
  .option("-d, --debug", "activate more debug messages. Can be set by env var DEBUG.", false)
  .parse(process.argv);

console.log(cli.debug)
```

Which gives me this error:

```
example.ts(7,7): error TS2322: Type 'Command' is not assignable to type 'Cli'.
  Property 'debug' is missing in type 'Command'.
```

I don't know how to add a property to the `Command` class, either in my file or in a new .d.ts file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your first code snippet and the following dependencies, I do not get an error:

```
"dependencies": {
    "commander": "^2.11.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/commander": "^2.9.1",
  "typescript": "^2.4.1"
}
```

Typescript interprets `cli.debug` as `any`. I guess the type declarations have been updated. So, if you are fine with `any`, the problem is solved.

If you really want to tell Typescript the type of `debug`, [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) would in principle be the way to go. It basically works like this:

```js
class C {
    public foo: number;
}

interface C {
    bar: number;
}

const c = new C();
const fooBar = c.foo + c.bar;
```

However, there is a problem: [`program.Command` is not a type but a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469868/). So, you cannot do this:

```js
interface program.Command {
    debug: boolean;
}
```

And while you can do this:

```js
function f1(): typeof program.Command {
    return program.Command;
}

type T = typeof program.Command;

function f2(): T {
    return program.Command;
}
```

You can neither do this:

```js
interface typeof program.Command {
}
```

Nor this:

```js
type T = typeof program.Command;

interface T {
}
```

I do not know whether this problem could be solved or not.

Comment: Just as a note Commander now ships with its own types, no need anymore to install `@types/commander`

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution, I don't really know if it's a good practice, but nontheless.

```
import { Command } from 'commander';
const cli = new Command();

interface InterfaceCLI{
  debug?: boolean;
}

cli
  .version("1.0.0")
  .usage("[options]")
  .option("-d, --debug", "activate more debug messages. Can be set by env var DEBUG.", false)
  .parse(process.argv);

const { debug } : InterfaceCli = <InterfaceCli><unknown>cli;
console.log(debug) // here debug is your cli.debug, I just used object destructuring
```

In the line before the last one I'm using [type casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204759/typescript-or-javascript-type-casting), I'm first casting to unkown for non-overlapping types, and then, finally, casting to our interface - `InterfaceCli`.